# How do we plot $u(4−t)$, where $u(t)$ is a step function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

How do we plot $u(4−t)$?

$u(t)$ is a step function:

$$u(t)=\begin{cases} 1&\text{ for }t \ge 0,\\
0 & \text{ for }t \lt 0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Search for heaviside step function.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the trick:

$u(x)$ will evaluate to 1 if $x$ is positive and zero otherwise, whatever be the expression you have in the place of x.

So, for $u(4-t)$, we need to see what values of $t$ keep $(4-t)$ positive...

Answer (score 2):

$u(4-t) = 1$ for $4-t\ge0$ so for $t\le4$

$u(4-t) = 0$ for $4-t\lt0$ so for $t\gt4$

Here is the plot:

[image]

Comment: Your math is correct, but your plot is backwards. As you noted it should be positive for values less than 4 and zero for values greater than 4, but your plot is the opposite.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'll update the answer with a new plot in a minute. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, I didn't mean to pick apart your answer, I just noticed as I was passing through.

Answer (score 1):

The unit step function has a single transition when the argument is zero.

Check where (4 - t) is zero, that's where the function switches from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0. To know which transition it is, try a value for t less than or greater than 4, for instance t = 0.